# How to take the property name and value and create a new object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am playing with some forms using jquery validation plugin

Now i am trying to send the form value to my server but i need send it information as JSON format.. so in my submitHandler method i am doing this...

```
var formData = JSON.stringify($("#form").serializeArray());
```

but now this variable formData contains it..

```
[ { name: 'nombre', value: 'ffgsdfgdfs' },
  { name: 'apellidos', value: 'gsdfgsdfg' },
  { name: 'email', value: 'dsfgg@gkfgd.com' },
  { name: 'usuario', value: 'fgsd' },
  { name: 'password', value: 'dksmfklsdm43' },
  { name: 'empresa', value: 'fkdmflksdmfkl' },
  { name: 'cif', value: 'mkfsdmfklsdmfkl' },
  { name: 'telefono', value: 'mfklsdmfklmsdfkl' },
  { name: 'direccion', value: 'mfklsdfmsdklfm' },
  { name: 'pais', value: 'klfmsdklfmsdklmf' },
  { name: 'localidad', value: 'kfmsdklfmsdklfm' },
  { name: 'cp', value: 'kfmsdklfmsdklfml' },
  { name: 'dominio', value: 'sde' },
  { name: 'termino', value: 'on' } ]
```

But it is not the format that i need, i would need something like...

```
formData ={
  nombre: 'ffgsdfgdfs',
  apellidos: 'gsdfgsdfg' ,
  email: 'dsfgg@gkfgd.com' ,
  usuario: 'fgsd',
  //.... etc etc
 } //this is what i would like to have
```

how can i do it? i've been trying with for in.... but i couldn't get the result that i expect

Comment: do you need an object for every pair?

Comment: it would be nice to have an object that cointains all the objects, i will edit my question

Comment: the actual data type is not possible, any value needs a key in an object. my question was do you want a single object with multiple properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map new objects and assign all to a single object.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'nombre', value: 'ffgsdfgdfs' }, { name: 'apellidos', value: 'gsdfgsdfg' }, { name: 'email', value: 'dsfgg@gkfgd.com' }, { name: 'usuario', value: 'fgsd' }, { name: 'password', value: 'dksmfklsdm43' }, { name: 'empresa', value: 'fkdmflksdmfkl' }, { name: 'cif', value: 'mkfsdmfklsdmfkl' }, { name: 'telefono', value: 'mfklsdmfklmsdfkl' }, { name: 'direccion', value: 'mfklsdfmsdklfm' }, { name: 'pais', value: 'klfmsdklfmsdklmf' }, { name: 'localidad', value: 'kfmsdklfmsdklfm' }, { name: 'cp', value: 'kfmsdklfmsdklfml' }, { name: 'dominio', value: 'sde' }, { name: 'termino', value: 'on' }],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(({ name, value }) => ({ [name]: value })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), example:

```js
const input = [
  {name: 'nombre', value: 'foo'},
  {name: 'apellidos', value: 'bar bar'},
  {name: 'email', value: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {name: 'usuario', value: 'foobar'}
];

let res = input.reduce((acc, {name, value}) => (acc[name] = value, acc), {});

console.log("Result is:", res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [{ name: 'nombre', value: 'ffgsdfgdfs' },
{ name: 'apellidos', value: 'gsdfgsdfg' },
{ name: 'email', value: 'dsfgg@gkfgd.com' },
{ name: 'usuario', value: 'fgsd' }];
var jsonData = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    jsonData[data[i].name] = data[i].value
}
```